# Are & and ; unary or binary operators?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

About the control operators `&` and `;`, from POSIX 2013:

For asynchronous lists,

> the format for running a command in the background is:
>
> ```
> command1 & [command2 & ... ]
> ```

For sequential lists,

> the format for executing commands sequentially shall be:
>
> ```
> command1 [; command2] ...
> ```

1. Is `&` unary or binary? Is `;` unary or binary?

   `&` and `;` look like binary, which operate the commands before and
   after them, and indicate that the execution order between the two
   commands is concurrent or sequential.

   `&` looks like unary, because every command in an asynchronous list
   is followed by a `&`.

   `;` doesn't look like unary, because the last command in a
   sequential list doesn't need a following `;`.

   Note: operators operates on operands. Depending on the number of
   operands, we can say an operator is unary, binary, .... Control
   operators, if I understand correctly, are operators on commands.
2. In a mixed list of `&` and `;`, what is the execution order between
   the component commands? What does each of `&` and `;` mean to the
   component commands?

   For example, in Bash

   ```
   $ echo 1 ; echo 2 & echo 3; echo 4 & echo 5
   1
   [1] 11089
   3
   2
   [2] 11090
   5
   4
   [1]-  Done                    echo 2
   [2]+  Done                    echo 4

   $ echo 1 ; echo 2 & echo 3; echo 4 & echo 5 ; echo 6 &
   1
   [1] 11100
   3
   [2] 11101
   5
   [3] 11102
   6
   4
   2
   [1]   Done                    echo 2
   [2]-  Done                    echo 4
   [3]+  Done                    echo 6
   ```

Answer (score 4):

1. I wouldn't normally think of them as "operators". I mean, typically operators return values. `&` and `;` do not. They instead end statements. But if you take them as operators, they operate on a single statement—so they'd be postfix unary operators, I suppose.
2. They're started left-to-right. Note that in the case of `&`, it runs in the background asynchronously: `echo 1 & echo 2 & echo 3` could print 1, 2, and 3 in any order (because even though they were *started* in order, the kernel may not schedule them such that they print in order). But `echo 1; echo 2; echo 3` will always print them in numerical order. `echo 1; echo 2 & echo 3` will always print 1 first, but 2 and 3 could be in either order.

Comment: " I mean, typically operators return values. & and ; do not". I think a control operator takes commands as inputs and output a command instead of a value. For example, in `command1 &`, the input to `&` is `command1`, and the output is a new command `command1 &`.

Comment: `;` doesn't look like unary, because the last command in a sequential list doesn't need a following `;`. Also `;` and `&` have meanings that indicate the execution order between the commands before and after them, and thus look like binary.

Comment: @Tim, in many contexts `;` and `<newline>` are synonymous.  [Read the POSIX shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

Comment: @Tim Well, you could say the final `;` is the newline—you can generally change newlines to `;` and vice versa. But you can also add a `;` at the end; e.g., if it's a binary operator, what does `ls;` mean? OTOH, `ls; ;` is a syntax error (which would be consistent with unary)

Comment: can `ls;`  mean that there is an empty command after `;`, so `;` is still binary? `ls; ;` doesn't have a nonempty command before the second `;`, so not sure if it is still counted as unary.

Comment: @Tim if it did, then why wouldn't `ls ; ;` be valid? Shell doesn't generally permit empty commands—e.g., `if…then…else…fi` doesn't allow empty commands either (e.g., if you want an empty `then` block, you have to explicitly use the `:` no-op command)

Comment: "`echo 1 & echo 2 & echo 3` could print 1, 2, and 3 in any order", you may add a `&` after `echo 3`.

Comment: @Tim correct, you could background the last one as well.

Comment: " I mean, typically operators return values. & and ; do not"  But they do,  in $?.

Comment: technically return values in `$?` in the case of `;` and `$!` in the case of `&`

Answer (score 2):

To add to derobert's answer, and dissect the command you include in your question:

```
echo 1 ; echo 2 & echo 3; echo 4 & echo 5 ; echo 6 &
```

This means in pseudocode:

```
print 1 (and complete this step before continuing)

start a process in the background that will eventually print 2,
  and keep going as soon as the process has been *started*

print 3 (and complete this before continuing)

start a background process that will eventually print 4,
  and keep going as soon as it has started

print 5 (complete this before continuing)

start a background process that will print 6.
```

Also note that any command to the shell must be terminated (whether with `&` or `;` or a newline or end of file or something else I'm not thinking of now), otherwise the shell won't know when to stop reading in more characters as part of that command and actually *run* the command.

Answer (score 0):

Note that bash has built-in commands that look very similar to the general case of a command line. I'm going to skip over that aspect.

But in general a command line is a series of commands separated by special punctuation, not operators.

A command is the name of the executable (which may be searched for via the PATH environment variable.)  That's the program that will be executed to perform the command.

After the command are white space separated strings that are passed to the command as strings. But there are special punctuation characters that must be escaped ( using a `\`'  or by using quotation marks) if you intend them to be part of an argument.

The punctuation characters have effects.

The special punctuation characters like '<', '>' and its kin define standard Input output and error to the command

'|' to terminate one command and pipe its standard output to the next commands standard input

';' to execute the previous command and wait for its completion.  i.e. run in the foreground.

'&' to execute the previous command, but continue on with the command line process without waiting for completion.  i.e. run in the background.

So be aware the intent of these syntactical marks is to allow you to put this stuff together do things like

`echo perl myperlprogram.pl \< mydata.txt | at 12:35`

Which makes a string using `echo` that is another shell command itself, to execute a perl program, and send that string to the `at` command to run it as a batch job later.  But note that the `<` is escaped, so it is passed as an argument to `echo` (which will send it to `at` as input), instead of setting standard input right away.   When the batch system and executes the command string THEN it will set the standard input of the perl program.

There are elaborations dealing with built in commands and things like parenthesis that can be learned once the basics are understood